# Run Python script as SQL Server Agent job

Tags: python, sql-server

Run this directly in command line will be fine:

```
"E:\path_to_interpretor\python" "E:\path_to_script\script.py"
```

But when I do "Operating System (CmdExec)" in MSSQL agent with the same thing, the job fails with the message:

Executed as user: DOMAIN\user. The step did not generate any output.  Process Exit Code -1073741515.  The step failed.

Note: E:\ is a mapped network drive.

Please advise. Much appreciated.